# Why the order was not filled though there was a last price at the moment, but no bid price?

Tags: price, bid-ask

On the Line price chart I see the last trade price was 18,26 with the volumes of 200. At the same time the best bid price is 18 and the best ask price is 18,29. I have placed an odd lot to sell 47 shares at 18,26, but it was not filled. How is possible that there were other trades with the price 42,26 but there were no bid? Cause if there a trade it means that somebody bought and somebody sold the share.

It was on the NYSE Exchange.

Comment: How many shares were listed for an ask of 18,29? Was your order listed as all-or-none? Did the 18,29 order go through before your order to sell for 18,26 was placed? What is the current ask price listed at?

Comment: There were 200 shares listed on ask 18,29. The order was not AON. I placed the order when there was 18,29 ask in the ladder table. But the most confusing thing is if there was a trade then somebody bought and somebod sold the security at 18,26. Why the there is no bid if somebody bought?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, there *was* an ask at 18,26 which was completely filled by the prior trade.  At that point, the *new* lowest ask was at 18,29, and your limit order at 18,26 would not be filled immediately, but would become the new highest bid price.

Comment: But later I see that lst trade price as 18,26. But according to the data from MD vendor there was no bid price. How`s that possible?

Comment: Does the vendor show _prior_ bids or just _current_ bids? Once a bid is filled is goes off of the trade sheet, so you wouldn't see it anymore, but I may be misunderstanding your question..

Comment: The Vendor shows current bids. It is clear that if the bid is filled it gows away. I have checked the charts in Bloomberg and see that the bid was never high as 18,26. But on the last trade chart i see prices as 18,26 and 18,28. So it means that somebody somebody bought and somebod sold the security at 18,26, isnt it? and there should be bid as 18,26? Thats what makes me confused.

Comment: "the bid was never high as 18,26" so Bloomberg shows previous bids? Was there an ask as low as 18,26? The only way a trade can get filled is when a market order matches up with (or a new limit order overlaps) a current high bid or low ask. It could be a data error if Bloomberg wasn't tracking the bid sheet often enough.

Comment: Bid,ask and last trade prices are the same both in Bloomberg and the file i recived from MD vendor. The Best bid - 18, best ask - 18,29 and the last trade price is 18,26 at the moment.

Comment: "at the moment" so you don't know what the best bid was when the trade was executed?

Comment: according to the bid chart the best bid was 18 and my ask was 18,26. But if I see the last trade price 18,26 doesnt it mean that somebody bought at 18,26 and so the best bid was higher than 18?

Comment: yes - "was". Once that bid order was filled the best bid is no longer 18,26.

Comment: According to the bid chart it was never higher then 18 and the broker confirmed it and said thats why my order was not filled.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out if you just know the "current" bit or if you can see the history of the bid.  If you see the history of the bid and it was never 18,26 the only was a trade was made is if the _ask_ was 18,26. If the ask was never 18,26 I can't see how a trade could be made other than directly on the pit floor (which is rare these days)